# Replacing a field with another value using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with following lines say;

```
100 200 300
50 120 200
60 500 340
```

I am writing a script to change the value of any field based upon user input. If user gives the column no ($colno) and row number ($rowno) in bash, I am using the following code to determine the exact field to be replaced.

```
awk -v i=$colno -v j=$rowno 'NR ==j {print $i}' file
```

So, if the user gives $colno as 1 and $rownno as 3 I can locate the field $1 in row 3 (60).

Now I want to permanently replace this value (60) with some other user given value ($new_val).

How can I do this using either sed or awk? This bit of code will allow me to change any field specified by the user with the new value specified by the user. The code should not change any other field, even with the same value.

Please help me. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: awk alone will not edit the file and sed requires the -i option.

Comment: By "permanently replace" do you mean write changes to the file with `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: If an in place edit is what you require,  I recommend you make a backup of your file somewhere else. If a user has a `$colno` or `$rowno` typo its not trivial to reverse.

Comment: Yes.. Backup is essential. Had overlooked.

Answer (score 6):

Just replace the column with the value required,

```
colno=1
rowno=3

awk -v i=$colno -v j=$rowno  -v newvalue=20 'NR ==j {$i=newvalue}1' file
100 200 300
50 120 200
20 500 340
```

The part, `{$i=newvalue}1` sets the value of `$1`, i.e. from your current example 3rd row and 1st column to the value set in `newvalue`. The `{}1` reconstructs each line based on the individual repalcements.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed, to replace at line `$rowno` the `$colno`th occurrence of non space characters with `$newtext` value:

```
sed -E "${rowno}s/[^ ]*( *)/${newtext}\1/${colno}" file
```